# Finding Lower Low in df but got Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, stockquotes

I have stock prices as df in this shape
[image: df]

I'm trying to find to find the lower low as I move from row to row and also higher high using the following code

```
while i<5:
print('index value',i)
if prices_df.loc[[i],['low']] < ll:
    ll = prices_df.loc[[i],['low']]
    print('ll update to', ll, "while i=", i)
elif prices_df.loc[[i],['high']] >hh:
    hh = prices_df.loc[[i],['high']]
    print('hh update to', hh, "while i=",i)
i += 1
continue
```

but I got the following error

> Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
>   ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: I'm not sure... but are you maybe just after `prices_df.head(5).agg({'low': 'min', 'high': 'max'})` ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Jon Clements.
The aggregate function in pandas will do the trick.

```
lower_low = prices_df.head(5).agg({'low':'min'})
higher_high = prices_df.head(5).agg({'high':'max'})

df_ll = prices_df[prices_df['low'].float.contains(lower_low) == True]
df_hh = prices_df[prices_df['low'].float.contains(higher_high) == True]
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to aggregate the lows. I just need to find the lowest value in the column labeled 'low'. I just need a single value not a df

Comment: You can iterate over rows in the df.head().df['column'] with a variable to store value.